# VSTO How to determine if Outlook Ribbon is in Simplified or Classic mode

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, add-in

How can one programmatically determine if an Outlook ribbon is displayed in Simplified or Classic mode?  Is there a related property and/or event which a VSTO add-in can access?  Have not been able to find any info on this. This would be used to adjust the label and image of our ribbon buttons depending on the ribbon mode via the callbacks provided in our ribbon XML declarations.  But maybe there is another way to do this?